# How to console.log something with "line number" in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, logging

In VsCode, React.js apps log with line numbers including the source file without any problem, but I couldn't achieve it with React-Native. It just appears like

```
LOG  Running "myapp" with {"rootTag":11}
```

on which, there is nothing showing where this log comes from.

Any help is appreciated..